# Maybe monad sample code in javascript explanation

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm starting or trying to learn functional programming monads.

So the first is Maybe. I'm  trying to convert the code with maybe monad.

```
function(fieldName, vals, fields) {
    var newValue = vals[fieldName];
    if (typeof(newValue) == 'undefined') {
        var elemFrom = fields[fieldName];
        if (elemFrom) {
            newValue = fields[fieldName]
        }
    }
    if (typeof (newValue) != 'undefined') {
        return newValue
    }
}
```

Here I have a bunch of checks for undefined which i think is good use of monay.

My problem is that I read that you pass value to the maybe monad and map function.

However in my case I replace the value inside the monad.

If I pass null the map method will do nothig since the value is undefined.

I'm not using a framework, i want simple implementation so I can understand it.

Should I add "else" method in the maybe monad class (function).

I have the opposite case "Do something if the value is undefined"

Can you suggest how to solve the issue

Thank you

Comment: There's nothing monadic about the code you posted. What is your actual question? Also, if you're trying to learn FP, monads are a *terrible* place to start.

Comment: The whole point of the question is how can i translate the code with Maybe monad because i couldn't

Comment: "*I read that you pass value to the maybe monad and map function*" - um, to use a *monad* you'd use the `chain` function (or `bind` or `flatMap` or whatever it is called)

Comment: I added the JavaScript tag. In the future please be sure to add that, the syntax highlighting relies on it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the function you posted could be rewritten as

```
const f = (a, b, c) => b[a] === undefined ? c[a] : b[a];
```

It isn't clear to me that this needs to be a function at all rather than being inlined wherever you want to use the relevant object properties, but maybe you're partially applying it or something, I'm not judging.

As for Maybe, a (very simple) implementation might look something like this:

```
class Maybe {
  static of (value) {
    return new Maybe(value);
  }

  // Proper solution here should be recursive to handle
  // nesting properly, but I'm lazy
  static equals (a, b) {
    return a.chain(x => x) === b.chain(x => x);
  }

  constructor(value) {
    this._value = value;
  }

  map (f) {
    // Does not distinguish null from undefined, but YMMV. Note
    // that if the Maybe value is null or undefined we never touch
    // f, that's the null propagation thing.
    return this._value == null ? this : new Maybe(f(this._value));
  }

  chain (f) {
    const result = this._value == null ? this : f(this._value);
    console.assert(result instanceof Maybe);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Now we can test that it obeys the Monad laws:

```
const a = 3;
const f = x => Maybe.of(x * x);
Maybe.of(a).chain(f) === f(a) // left identity
Maybe.equals(Maybe.of(5).chain(Maybe.of), Maybe.of(5)); // right identity
```

And that it's a valid Functor

```
Maybe.equals(Maybe.of(3).map(x => x), Maybe.of(3)); // identity
Maybe.equals(                                       // composition
  Maybe.of(3).map(x => x + 2).map(x => x * 3), 
  Maybe.of(3).map(compose(x => x * 3, x => x + 2))
);
```

Sweet.

So now, to your function. It would be rewritten as

```
const f = (a, b, c) => {
  return b[a] === undefined ? Maybe.of(c[a]) : Maybe.of(b[a]);
}
```

Perhaps you see now the reason for my confusion, Maybe isn't really saving you much here. But if I were using Maybe I'd rewrite the whole thing like this:

```
const or = (a, b) => {
  return Maybe.of(a == null ? b : a);
}
```

And then I would just pass in the property accesses:

```
const obj1 = { a: 2, c: 3 };
const obj2 = { b: 4 };
const prop = "a"
const result = or(obj1["prop"], obj2["prop"]); // Maybe(2)
```

### Update

Credit to @Bergi in the comments reminding me about Alternative. You could add a method to the Maybe class above like so:

```
alt (x) {
  if (!(x instanceof Maybe)) {
    throw new TypeError("Expected a Maybe");
  }
  return this.chain(x => x) == null ? x : this;
}

// semantics

Maybe.of(null).alt(Maybe.of(3)); // Maybe(3)
Maybe.of(2).alt(Maybe.of(4));    // Maybe(2)

// usage
Maybe.of(obj1[prop]).alt(Maybe.of(obj2[prop]));
```

Note that this doesn't totally satisfy as an implementation of Alternative (you'd also need a zero/empty method) but you can read [here](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#alternative) and [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Alternative_and_MonadPlus) for more details. This is *probably* the best replacement for the function you posted.

Comment: You might want to implement an `Alternative` instance on your `Maybe` data type - that's what is actually needed here.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, added a quick-and-dirty method with links to fantasyland and the Alternative class in Control.Applicative. Please let me know if I missed anything else.

Comment: I think it should be `Maybe.from(null).alt(Maybe.from(3))`

Comment: @Bergi fixed it.

Comment: Reviewing this, your `chain` method seems to be totally off. It should read simply `return this._value == null ? this : f(this._value);` (where the `f(this._value)` could be asserted to be an `instanceof Maybe` - not *any* monad).

Comment: @Bergi edited again and you are correct, the implementation I posted did not actually preserve right identity. That's what I get for typing without actually running the code.

Comment: Thank you, very nice explanation, so istn alt method the same as the chain ? What is the difference ? And lastly why it is called functional programming since the Maybe is kind of a class/object this is confusion for me

Comment: @user2693928 I wrote it as a class, because it's easy to write it that way It doesn't really matter, as the instances are immutable (by convention at least), and that's the real core difference between OOP and FP. `chain` you can think of as removing a layer of nesting. If you have `Maybe(Maybe(5))` and you have a function `f` that takes a `Maybe`, you can't just pass the nested Maybe, so you use `chain`. `alt` is different, in the case of `Maybe` it functions kind of like a logical `or`: if you have a  `Maybe(null)` to start then you get Maybe of whatever value you pass to `alt`, otherwise

Comment: you get the original `Maybe`, in the same way that in bare JS `const five = null || 5; const three = 3 || 5;`